# Android - trying to save ArrayList <String> into SharedPreferences as a JSON String using GSON - But filthy NullPointerException appears

Tags: android, json, arraylist, sharedpreferences, gson

Been at this for a while, can't seem to see what the problem is.

I am getting a NullPointerException when attempting to save ArrayList to JSON, by all means skip ahead to the bottom where it is marked.

I have used GSON to save object to and from JSON before, but they were whole objects not ArrayLists..

Relevant code:

```
private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES = "shared_preferences";

// Shared Preferences containing JSON object of saved usernames
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

// Saved usernames
ArrayList <String> savedUsernames;
```

onCreate()...

```
// Get sharedPreferences
    sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Attempting to either way ensure savedUsernames is initialized to something.

```
// If usernames are saved, initialize savedUsernames with them or else initiliaze blank but ready
    if (sharedPreferences.contains(SAVED_NAMES))
    {
        getSavedUsernames();
    }
    else
    {
        savedUsernames = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
```

Button Listener that saves current displayed username to savedUsernames ArrayList

```
case R.id.bSaveUsername:

            // Add textview text to ArrayList
            savedUsernames.add(tvCurrentUsername.getText().toString());

            // Addition, add change for deletion
            changeHasBeenMade = true;

            // Toast for feedback
            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Added to list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
```

I have a boolean that goes true when each change is made. This is the onPause()

```
// If there is anything to save, save
    if (changeHasBeenMade)  
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        saveUsernames();
    }
```

Calling saveUsernames() which is where the problem is (Line highlighted below)

```
// On pause, saveUsernames
private void saveUsernames()
{
    if (D) Log.i(TAG, "savedUsernames() start");


            /**** PROBLEM LINE ****/
    String savingNamesJSON = gson.toJson(savedUsernames);
            /**** PROBLEM LINE ****/


    // Create editor, save JSON string and commits
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(SAVED_NAMES, savingNamesJSON).commit();

    if (D) Log.i(TAG, "savedUsernames() end");
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time! Appreciate it

Comment: where do you initialize Gson?

Comment: Please include the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you Zoltan! That was the all I missed out! It's always the small things. Thanks